# jquery remove nodes and keep children

Tags: jquery, html, children, parents

I am very ashamed to post this question but I have not managed to get use of unwrap or replaceWith methods in Jquery for that need.

My problem is simple : I need to remove some nodes (jquery selectors) of an html code without losing the children of these nodes.

Here is a Jsfiddle that demonstrate the result of my unsightly code used to reach my goal https://jsfiddle.net/uddaeh1u/15/ (yes it's works...)

```js
// var content : the html source code of the wysiwyg

var result = '';
$(content).contents().each(function(){
    var addContent = '';
    // textNode
    if(this.nodeType == 3) {
        // Text Node
        result+= $(this).text();
    } else if(this.nodeType == 1 && $(this).hasClass('atwho-inserted')) {
        // if is an Object Node with the target class
        // I only keep it's contents (means that ".atwho-inserted" is not kept)
        result+= $(this).html();
    } else {
        // in any other case I keep it entirely
        result+= this.outerHTML;
    }
});
```

Could you find me a really better code (with unwrap method) ?

Thank you a lot :)

Comment: I notice that you are running 2 Bootstrap's CSS of different versions in your JSFiddle.

Comment: In your **result** code, the `<p>` is also removed. Is this expected?

Comment: @aManHasNoName no it's not... well seen...it's another problem !

Comment: thank you @MiquelAl.Vicens ... it's my first JsFiddle ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this one would please you.
Notice modification of var `tmp`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var content = $('.start').html();
  $('.startCode code').text(content);
  
  var tmp = $(content);
  $('.atwho-inserted', tmp).children().unwrap();
  var result = tmp[0].outerHTML; // or tmp.html(); but would lose the outermost tag
  
  $('.result').html(result);
  $('.resultCode').text(result);
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:10px;
}
.atwho-inserted{
  background-color:red;
}
pre code, .wrap{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well">All selectors ".atwho-inserted" are in "background-color:red" and have to be removed without losing its children.</div>
      <hr/>
      <div class="start">
        <p>
          <span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="@fac" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="user_mention" data-identifier="8930">@facticeuserr</span>
          </span>
          <br /> some lorem ipsum text
          <span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="#acc" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="tag_mention" data-identifier="484">#accessibilité</span>
          </span>
          <br>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" data-filename="3">
          <br />
          <b>hello</b>
          <br>
          <span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="#acc" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="tag_mention" data-identifier="653">#Accompagnement</span>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <pre class="startCode"><code></code></pre>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="col-xs-6">    
      <div class="well">Here the result<br /> it's works but code is not optimized</div>
      <hr/>
      <div class="result"></div>
      <pre class="resultCode"><code></code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but can you try to work with $(content) that contains the whole code.
Indeed, it works well if I only use the jquery selector $('.atwho-inserted') that point on the DOM however I need to start from a recovered content stored in that variable. And here is my problem...

Comment: Your code snippet keep the .atwho-inserted elements

Comment: Great that works (I made a mistake) ! https://jsfiddle.net/uddaeh1u/23/

Comment: not sure what you meant... in that last fiddle I see the exact same outcome in `result` as in `tmpContent` (which BTW does not use `:first-child` as states description in 3rd case)

Comment: ok, now I saw it. Change to this `var result = tmpContent[0].outerHTML;` and you won't loos that outer `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is to only remove `span.atwho-inserted` without its children and the rest of the DOM remains the same, you can do so by:

```
$('.start .atwho-inserted').children(':first-child').unwrap();
```

First, select the elements with class `.atwho-inserted`, then find their respective first-child and perform `unwrap`.

`unwrap` removes the selector immediate parent wrapper and leaves behind the children.

And you are good to go!

Comment: It seems a nice solution however in my case I work on a variable that contains the html code. unwrap() only returns the unwrapped jquery objects but not the whole code sanitized.

Comment: since i compared your result and mine, they are the same except for the `<p>` tag i already mentioned in the question comment.

Comment: Sorry, here is new jsFiddle with your solution :)
https://jsfiddle.net/uddaeh1u/18/
I just discover the "update" button there...

Answer (score 0):

basically `outerHTML` is what you want to replace with `innerHTML` (*unwrap*)
check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML#Browser_compatibility

```js
$('#trigger').click(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $('.atwho-inserted').each(function() {
    this.outerHTML = $(this).html();
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:10px;
}

.atwho-inserted{
  background-color:red;
}

pre code, .wrap{
  white-space: pre-line;
}

#trigger {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="trigger">Click to trigger edition</button>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="well">All selectors ".atwho-inserted" are in "background-color:red" and have to be removed without losing its children.</div>
      <div class="start">
        <p>
          <span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="@fac" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="user_mention" data-identifier="8930">@facticeuserr</span>
          </span>
          <br /> some lorem ipsum text
          <span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="#acc" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="tag_mention" data-identifier="484">#accessibilité</span>
          </span>
          <br>
          <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" data-filename="3">
          <br />
          <b>hello</b>
          <br>
          <span class="atwho-inserted" data-atwho-at-query="#acc" contenteditable="false">
            <span class="tag_mention" data-identifier="653">#Accompagnement</span>
          </span>
        </p>
      </div>
      <pre class="startCode"><code></code></pre>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">    
      <div class="well">Here the result<br /> it's works but code is not optimized</div>
      <div class="result"></div>
      <pre class="resultCode"><code></code></pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you !
However I havn't find the way to use this process directly on my variable "content". Unwrap() return the unwrapped Object jQuery or apply directly on the Dom.

example of use : 
    var content = $(messageContent).summernote('code');
    $(content).find('.atwho-inserted').each(function() {
        this.outerHTML = $(this).html();
    });
    console.log($(content));

Comment: Sorry...i haven't found the way of publishing code in a comment here...

Comment: for inline code use back-ticks `` and `there you go`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another JsFiddle where i added the unwrap() solution
https://jsfiddle.net/uddaeh1u/21/

```js
$(content).find('.atwho-inserted').children(':first-child').unwrap();
```

I think the problem is that unwrap() only returns the jquery Objects unwrapped and can only apply on the DOM (not from a variable treated as a Dom Object).

Comment: You haven't modified the value of `content` after initialising, so it is still `$('.start').html()`

Comment: comment first line of second solution, add this line at the last `$('.result2').find('.atwho-inserted').children(':first-child').unwrap();`

Comment: `$(content)` didn't work since you started with an jquery object(see its value), what i'm doing is directly manipulating the DOM (no need to store the value)

Comment: I understand your work of course but I must not change the DOM. How can I store the result of your code `$('.result2').find('.atwho-inserted').children(':first-child').unwrap();` ??

Comment: Thing is : My wysiwyg with some other plugins generate a html code that I must change *before* sending it to the server. But I must not change the Dom directly, so I have to work on a copy.